# C# Quartz.net : do RescheduleJob and UnscheduleJob stop currently executing jobs?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, jobs

From what little i could find, it seems that the RescheduleJob and UnscheduleJob methods of the scheduler stop jobs if the jobs are executing at the time the methods are called.

However that is only conjecture. I need confirmation about this.
Do those methods stop the execution of jobs they are called on?

Comment: you could set up an experiment and try it

Comment: Since it's a big project in the company i work in, i was hoping being able to get an answer without doing that.

Comment: make a test project, don't do it with your live jobs and code.